# Hive: using RegexSerDe with multiple tabs

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I need to load txt table to hive. Txt table contains tab separated columns of a table. The thing is that there are columns separated by more than one tab:

```
135.124.143.193   20150601013300 http://newsru.com/4712386 253 486 ok
```

There are three tabs between first and second column and exactly one tab between rest of the columns.

I have figured out I need to use **RegexSerDe** in order to process that correctly. 
I am trying

```
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    with serdeproperties ("input.regex" = "(\\S+)\\t+")
```

but as I attempt to select from result table I get:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: Number of matching groups doesn't match the number of columns
```

Comment: Try it like this using an alternation asserting the end of the string. If there is not tab at the end, you will not match the last value.  `(\S+)(?:\t+|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is not tab at the end of the string, you will not match the last value and this will only get the first capturing group.

What you might do is match all number of groups separated by 1+ tabs.

As per the comments this pattern works for you.

```
(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wRCXHw/1)

If you want to match exactly 3 tabs after the first group, you could use a quantifier `\\t{3}` instead of the `\\t+`

If you want to match exacty all the columns, you might also use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string.

```
^(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)$
```

Comment: Tried precisely this as ```"input.regex" = "(\\S+)(?:\\t+|$)"``` parameter, but still getting the same error

Comment: @EgorMaksimov And if you use the exact number of capturing groups? `^(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)$` See https://regex101.com/r/k8pewy/1

Comment: ```(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+).*``` did the trick. Thanks for the help man!

Comment: @EgorMaksimov Great that it works :) I have updated the answer with the pattern.